# How to use typescript in nativescript?

Tags: typescript, nativescript

Can someone give me a detail steps how to setup typescript environment for nativescript?

lets say `import fooModule = require('ui/image');` won't give me a red underline and error while compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They ship with typescript definitions as `tns-definitions-*.tgz` that you need to extract and *include* in your project. Download is available from releases page e.g. https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/releases/tag/v1.1.0

Note: It will get better once we have : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2338

Answer (score 6):

As of NativeScript version 1.5, TypeScript is really easy to set up just by running

```
tns install typescript
```

inside your project directory.
Here is a video on how to get set up: [Hello World native iOS mobile app using TypeScript and NativeScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JDXnduTlgs)